# Simple Flex and grid layout in Tailwind

Tags: tailwind-css

I'm trying to create a layout that is 2/3 wide on the left, and 1/3 wide on the right at md: and larger sizes.  Smaller than that, I would like the two to be on top of each other.

When I do this, the flex works at smaller sizes, but my containers are not the size I anticipated:

```
<div class="flex flex-wrap md:flex-wrap-reverse">
<div class="col-span-8 ...">

...

</div>
<div class="col-span-4 ...">

...

</div>
</div>
```

Comment: col span is for grid..... which is what you probably should be using from the sounds of it

Comment: @KeithNicholas that's what I had originally - grid grid-flow-col , however, in that case it doesn't move down at smaller screen sizes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @KeithNicholas I found my answer - I changed a prior attempt to this:

```
<div class="grid md:grid-flow-col ">
<div class="col-span-8 ...">

...

</div>
<div class="col-span-4 ...">

...

</div>
</div>
```